# Sharprepository Autofac InstancePerApiRequest in Webapi environment not working

Tags: autofac, sharp-repository

Does anyone have a working example of sharprepository intergration with autofac using InstancePerApiRequest for DbContext?

I am registering my dbcontext thusly:

```
builder.RegisterType<AuditTestEntities>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerApiRequest();
```

If I remove the InstancePerApiRequest, sharprepository is able to get a dbcontext. But with the InstancePerApiRequest, I get the error message pasted below. Basically the crux of the error is, I suspect, the way sharprepository makes the call:

> No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.

The full error stack:

> iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create, Exception=System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'AccountRepository'. ---> Could not resolve type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' using the 'AutofacDependencyResolver'.  Make sure you have configured your Ioc container for this type.  View the InnerException for more details. (See inner exception for details.) ---> SharpRepository.Repository.Ioc.RepositoryDependencyResolverException: Could not resolve type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' using the 'AutofacDependencyResolver'.  Make sure you have configured your Ioc container for this type.  View the InnerException for more details. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.

Comment: Just a few questions to help clarify.  

1) How is AccountRepository defined?  Is it using ConfigurationBasedRepository or inheriting from a specific type of repository like Ef5Repository?

2) Are you setting up the SharpRepository dependency resolution bits by calling RepositoryDependencyResolver.SetDependencyResolver()?

3) Are you using the builder.RegisterSharpRepository() provided with the Ioc.AutoFac package?

Comment: It is using ConfigurationBasedRepository. I have done the             builder.RegisterSharpRepository() call at startup as well as  setup RepositoryDependencyResolver.SetDependencyResolver(new SharpRepository.Ioc.Autofac.AutofacDependencyResolver(container)). As I mentioned, DbContext resolves when not in InstancePerApiRequest mode.

Comment: I was able to get Windsor Castle to work properly, i.e to share DbContext amongst all Sharp Repositories. But Ninject, on the other hand isn't able to share. Each Repository instance gets its own DbContext despite the InRequestScope setting. Which is the reason for this whole exercise of figuring out what's going on.

Comment: Depending on if you have the dbContextType setup in the config file, the repository factory for Ef5 will either call RepositoryDependencyResolver.Current.Resolve(dbContextType) where dbCOntextType is the Type included in the config file or it calls RepositoryDependencyResolver.Current.Resolve<DbContext>().  For Autofac that means it calls container.Resolve<DbContext>() or container.Resolve(DbContextType).  And for Ninject that is kernel.Get<DbContextType>() or kernel.Get(DbContextType).  Can you call those directly and see if it resolves properly?  Or call RepositoryDependencyResolver Resolve

Comment: I was able to call RepositoryDependencyResolver.Current.Resolve<DbContext>() as MyEntities; as well as GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(DbContext)) as MyEntities; and then use the DbContext to return data from the database. Perhaps this is something to do with it being a webapi project.

Comment: The Ef5 Repository Factory calls RepositoryDependencyResolver.Current.Resolve<DbContext>() so if that works I'm not sure where the issue would be coming from.  Are you defining a dbContextType in your web.config file for the ef5Repository element?  If you could send me a sample project that shows the issue with Autofac I'd like to look at it so we can get it resolved if it's an issue with the SharpRepository Autofac dependency resolver itself.

Answer (score 1):

Okay found the issue.  There is a problem with using the SharpRepository AutofacDependencyResolver when using the MVC or Web API integration and trying to use the scope InstancePerApiRequest or InstancePerHttpRequest.  Autofac expects those items to be resolved from the System.Web.DependencyResolver.Current instead of from the Autofac IContainer directly as the AutofacDependencyResolver is currently doing.

Here is how you can fix the issue right now until we make an overload for AutofacDependencyResolver that fixes the issue.

You will need to create your own dependency resolver within your project like this one:

```
public class CustomAutofacDependencyResolver : BaseRepositoryDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IDependencyResolver _resolver;

    public CustomAutofacDependencyResolver(IDependencyResolver resolver)
    {
        _resolver = resolver;
    }

    protected override T ResolveInstance<T>()
    {
        return _resolver.GetService<T>();
    }

    protected override object ResolveInstance(Type type)
    {
        return _resolver.GetService(type);
    }
}
```

And then register it with SharpRepository so it will use it to resolve the DbContext and then it will work as expected.

```
RepositoryDependencyResolver.SetDependencyResolver(new CustomAutofacDependencyResolver(DependencyResolver.Current));
```

** Update**
I was testing with MVC and able to replicate the error and fix it but that doesn't work with Web API.  I am used to using StructureMap where it works fine using the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.

It seems the issue is that Autofac needs a IDependencyScope that you can access from the HttpRequestMessage but I'm not seeing a way to get to that outside of the ApiController.  This describes the issue and the reason: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/autofac/b3HCmNE_S2M/oMmwFE5uD80J

Unfortunately right now I'm at a bit of a loss on the best way to handle this.  But I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: Unfortunately webapi is a different beast compared to mvc. There is no DependencyResolver.Current. So although this may very well work for MVC, I am unable to use this solution for Webapi project.

Comment: I just saw your comment about getting the sample project. Do you still want it? Also should I start a new question to resolve sharing DbContext in web api with ninject setting? Ninject doesn't blow up like Autofac does, but it still gives each repository its own dbcontext instance.

Comment: How about you post an issue on GitHub for us to take a look at the Ninject issue.  I tested it with an MVC project but not Web API yet.  If you post something here we can get it figured out for you: https://github.com/SharpRepository/SharpRepository/issues

Comment: This is same as your first suggestion. Even so, I copied it into my proj and tried again with the same results, i.e ".... Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or LifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself."

Comment: I did this in a Web API project of mine and it worked for me.  If you'd like me to look at it more then I think I'll need a simple project that can replicate what you are seeing.  You can email something like that to me if you;d like.

Comment: I can send it to you tomorrow. Where do i send it?

Comment: jtreuting at fairwaytech dot com

Comment: I just emailed you the project. Let me know if you need any clarifications.

Comment: Can you post this Autofac issue to Github so that it is recorded there and we can continue the discussion there and when we get a fix we can post the answer back here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to get mine working by changing the lifetime scope to `InstancePerLifetimeScope`.  I don't know whether this has any unforeseen consequences or not.  Everything appears to be working fine for me so far.

Comment: Didn't work for me. First api request call went through alright, but the second one caused exception about the dbcontext being disposed already.